# 2014 Jeep Grand Cherokee -- quiet whine from steering wheel -- what's causing it?

Tags: jeep, power-steering, steering, grand-cherokee

I have a 2014 Grand Cherokee Laredo.

There is a very low high pitched whine that comes from the steering wheel. If I turn the wheel two inches to the right or left, the whine goes quiet. If I let go of the wheel and it re-centres, the whine comes back.

It's very low,, but high pitched. Drives me batty.

I checked the power steering fluid level and it's on Max.

Any idea what could cause this, and how to make it go away?

Thanks!

UPDATE: You can hear the sound in this guy's YouTube video ... like a high pitched whine ... http://youtube.com/watch?v=RqsuMpUBxag

Comment: It's probably your power steering rack (I'm assuming it has a rack, considering how new it is). I'd take it back to the dealership and get them to fix it. As it's only a 2014, depending on when you actually purchased it, you can have them fix it under what is called an *adjustment period*, it just has to be less than 12 months since you bought the vehicle (most companies do this).

Comment: It's actually a used car, 20 months old, and out of factory warranty.  You can hear the sound in this guy's YouTube video ... like a high pitched whine ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqsuMpUBxag

Comment: I'm hearing two noises in the video. One is a continual high pitched whine, the other is intermittent and occurs only when the steering wheel is being turned. The second noise is more like a what you'd hear when you cramp the steering (run the steering to the end of its turn and try to make it go further). Can you say which one you are talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about the continual high pitched whine.  Any ideas?

Comment: No ideas. I don't think the noise you hear in the video is steering related was the reason I was asking. You say your noise is intermittent under certain circumstances. Nothing is popping to mind here.

Comment: Thanks for trying -- my whine is steering related because it stars and stops as I turn the wheel.

Comment: I still think I'd look at the steering mechanism (rack & pinion) as the issue, where it is making noise in the neutral position. Once fluid pressure is applied due to turning the steering wheel, the noise abates. Usually it's the other way around, where it's making noise when doing work, not when at rest. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the comments section on this [YouTube video](http://youtu.be/c81pit8miMY), it seems to be a common issue related to the electric power steering motor.

It is likely that there will be a technical service bulletin issued as to what the recommended course of action is.

Comment: I don't know if it's bad form to link to another answer site, but this guy "Vlad" agrees with you and sounds very authoritative:  http://www.justanswer.com/jeep/75sb6-jeep-grand-cherokee-laredo-e-p-s.html